# How to escape from zombie grab?

Tags: dead-rising

How to escape from zombie grab before a QTE prompt appears on-screen?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wiggling the left stick horizontally seems to
guarantee a quick escape. If I do nothing I will always die no matter how healthy my character is.
There's also unlockable skill moves that provide an alternative method for escaping:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There should be a button prompt to mash a random face button.

Comment: There was a tutorial screen explaining that a button prompt only appears when being grabbed by several zombies at once.